# Why am I getting warnings about this code example? What is proper?

Tags: c

I'm learning some C, and was reading up on `scanf` from [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm) where the following code block is included:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char str1[20], str2[30];

   printf("Enter name: ");
   scanf("%s", &str1);

   printf("Enter your website name: ");
   scanf("%s", &str2);

   printf("Entered Name: %s\n", str1);
   printf("Entered Website:%s", str2);

   return(0);
}
```

However I get warnings that:

```
"Format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[20]'
```

Is the tutorial wrong?

Comment: Immediately stop learning C from that tutorial. It is wrong.

Comment: @Doug Smith Take into account that even published books of well-known authors contains bugs in program examples.:)

Comment: @Doug Smith By the way in this phrase "I'm a web designer playing around with iOS from England" what is from England iOS or you?:)

Comment: I think you should immediately signal this tutorial to its author, if possible. His/her tutorial is bad and he/she should feel bad.

Comment: @Mark Lakata Found the [errant tutorial code](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char str1[20], str2[30];

   printf("Enter name: ");
   scanf("%19s", str1);
         //^^   ^ Removed address operator
         //So only the right amount of characters gets read   

   printf("Enter your website name: ");
   scanf(" %29s", str2);
        //^ Added space to catch line breaks from the buffer

   printf("Entered Name: %s\n", str1);
   printf("Entered Website:%s", str2);

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: @DougSmith Yes, also see my comments what i changed, hope my answer helps you! (Also if this was a tutorial i would search a new one)

Comment: That's better than the original code, but it's still vulnerable to a buffer overrun.

Comment: @KeithThompson updated my answer, should be better now

Comment: I'd also suggest about `fgets`.

Answer (score 7):

There is a bug in the example of the tutorial.

Change:

```
scanf("%s", &str1);
```

to

```
scanf("%s", str1);
```

`s` conversion specifier requires a pointer to `char` but you are passing a pointer to an array.

Comment: Indeed, the tutorial is buggy.

Answer (score 3):

The lines

```
scanf("%s", &str1);
```

and

```
scanf("%s", &str2);
```

are indeed wrong (at the very least, they both contain a typo).  They *should* be written as

```
scanf("%s", str1);  // no & operator
```

and

```
scanf("%s", str2); // ditto
```

Arrays and array expressions are special in C.  Except when it is the operand of the sizeof or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted (decay) to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

The *expression* `str1` has type "20-element array of `char`".  If `str1` appears in a context where it's not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it will be converted to an expression of type "pointer to `char`", and the value of the expression will be the same as `&str1[0]`; this is why you don't need to use the `&` for reading strings, since the array expression will be treated as a pointer.  However, when it's the operand of the unary `&` operator, the conversion rule doesn't apply, and the type of the expression `&str1` is "pointer to 20-element array of `char`" (`char (*)[20]`).  Hence your warning.

The *value* of `str1` and `&str1` will be the same (the address of the first element array is the same as the address of the array), but the types of the expressions are different, and type matters.  A pointer to `char` will be treated differently from a pointer to array of `char`.

90% of C books and tutorials are *crap*; be very skeptical of any C reference that isn't the actual standard.  Harbison & Steele's [C: A Reference Manual](http://www.careferencemanual.com) (currently 5th edition) has been my go-to reference since the late '80s, but even it has small errors.