# Name wont appear in the bottom part of my program

Tags: c++

this program is used for my assignment but the bottom part of the program doesnt show the the name inputted why is that?
You Guys can test it in Dev++ to see how it works.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

    char n4m3[100],Pos;
    int rt,hr,gI,T,td,ss=100,pi=100,hc=100,NetIn;

    printf("    ==Employee Salary==");
    printf("\n Name:");
    scanf(" %s",&n4m3);

    printf("\n -Position- \n  C-CEO\n  V-VP\n  S-Supervisor\n  T-Team Leader");
    printf("\n Postion:");
    scanf(" %s",&Pos);

    if (Pos=='C'||Pos=='c')
        {
            rt=500;
            printf("\n  CEO Rate:500");
        }
        else if (Pos=='V'||Pos=='v')
        {
            rt=400;
            printf("\n  VP Rate:400");
        }
        else if (Pos=='S'||Pos=='s')
        {
            rt=300;
            printf("\n  Supervisor Rate:300");
        }
        else if (Pos=='T'||Pos=='t')
        {
            rt=200;
            printf("\n  Team Leader Rate:200");
        }
    else printf("   Invalid Input");

    printf("\n  Number of Hours Worked:");
    scanf("%d",&hr);

    printf("\n  ==Summary==");
    gI=rt*hr;
    printf("\n Gross Income:%d",gI);

    if (gI>=4000)

        T=gI*.4;
    else if (gI>=3000)
        T=gI*.3;
    else if (gI>=2000)
        T=gI*.2;
    else if (gI>=1000)
        T=gI*.1;

        printf("\n Tax:%d",T);
        td=T+ss+pi+hc;
        printf("\n Total Deductions:%d",td);
        NetIn=gI-td;
        printf("\n Net Income is %d",NetIn);
        printf("\n----------------------");
        printf("\n Mr./Ms. %s your net income is %d",n4m3,NetIn);
}
```

*this part should show the name and Net income of the user but it doesnt show the name*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. **Simplify.** This is not just for our convenience, it is for the development of your coding skills-- it is a vital ability. Simplify this code as much as you can while still producing the same error; the bug will be in the code that is left, like a fish in the last puddle of a drained pond.

Comment: Suggestion: try changing `scanf(" %s",&n4m3);` to `scanf(" %s",n4m3);`.

Comment: @paulsm4 its still the same no name is shown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working because `scanf` wants a `char *` and you are passing it a `char (*)[100]`. To fix this, remember that an array is a contiguous block of memory, and the name of the array is a pointer to the start of that memory. Therefore, `n4m3` is already a `char *`, and there is no need to take the address of it with the `&`.

The line should be `scanf(" %s",n4m3); //no '&'`.

### Relevant Notes

I found this by compiling your code with warnings enabled. You should **always** do this! Compiling on Linux or Mac with clang flags `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` yields several warnings for this code. The relevant one is:

```
tmp.cpp:9:13: error: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type
  'char (*)[100]' [-Werror,-Wformat]
scanf(" %s",&n4m3);
        ~~  ^~~~~
```

Googling the error brought me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27805793/why-am-i-getting-warnings-about-this-code-example-what-is-proper), which fixes the problem. Another warning is:

```
tmp.cpp:51:10: error: variable 'T' is used uninitialized whenever 'if' condition
      is false [-Werror,-Wsometimes-uninitialized]
else if (gI>=1000)
         ^~~~~~~~
tmp.cpp:54:24: note: uninitialized use occurs here
    printf("\n Tax:%d",T);
                       ^
tmp.cpp:51:6: note: remove the 'if' if its condition is always true
else if (gI>=1000)
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
tmp.cpp:5:15: note: initialize the variable 'T' to silence this warning
int rt,hr,gI,T,td,ss=100,pi=100,hc=100,NetIn;
              ^
               = 0
```

There are more warnings that I'll let your compiler (once you set it up correctly) find. On Windows, increase Visual Studio's [warning levels](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/12/14/off-by-default-compiler-warnings-in-visual-c.aspx) by using [these instructions](http://mihai-nita.net/2010/05/10/changing-default-vs-warning-level/). You will save many hours of work if you let your compiler analyze code for you.

Comment: Don't forget `scanf(" %s",&Pos);`

Comment: @Beta: `Pos` actually should be passed by address. It's of type `char`, and `scanf` wants `char *`, and passing it the address of `Pos` accomplishes this. While both `n4m3` and `Pos` are originally of type `char`, the `[100]` in `n4m3[100]` changes `n4m3` to type `char *`. This doesn't happen  with `Pos`. [Here](http://www.cdecl.org/) is a website to help decipher a type. [Here](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) is a good tutorial on the subject.

Comment: I wasn't referring to the "&", I was referring to the "%s".

Comment: @Beta Ahh. I didn't notice. That would be better with `scanf(" %c", &Pos);`, wouldn't it?

Answer (score -1):

when you will input a string without spaces then it will work fine . 
but if you are going to enter a string with spaces its behaviour changes as it is going to read the string only upto the space.

For this you can use getline or fgets or sscanf in your code instead of scanf .i.e

try to replace the line  :

```
scanf(" %s",&n4m3);
```

with

`fgets(n4m3,100,stdin);`

it should work for sure.

Comment: @Beta no i dint got any error and fgets is not giving any error as well when i compiled and gave the required result .

Comment: @ShawnAdrianneCuaresma you can see on ideone the fgets is giving the required result :   http://ideone.com/yi9jHC

Comment: the issue may be there as fgets is  compiler dependent . I have got this type of error earlier and might be 
 while (getchar() != '\n');   
this statement could clear the issue . this line will remove any newline character in the buffer  .

Comment: If you couldn't reproduce the error, then you can't be sure your solution solved it.

Comment: @Beta link i posted for ideone ,change the code to initial code of the query then again same error(issue) is there . might be there is a issue with dev++ as i also tried the query on my terminal .

Answer (score -2):

Works as expected. Just command line window with result is closed just after your program ends, so you can't see it.

Comment: Umm... no. The problem is more serious than that.

Comment: Maybe, but he didn't provide any test data, and this is so common mistake so I have to mention it.